# Monty's choice of door to open when the car is behind the door initially chosen by the contestant

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, monty-hall

In the Monty Hall game, suppose that whenever the car is behind the door initially chosen by the contestant (so that Monty Hall may open either one of the remaining two doors), he chooses to open the door labeled with the smaller number. Is the probability of winning upon switching still 2/3 or is it 1/2? My considerations suggest that not only is it still 2/3, but also it is 2/3 no matter how Monty chooses a door to open when he does have a choice. Am I wrong?

If computer simulations (Monte Carlo) *confirm or contradict the assertion* that it is still 2/3, I would like to know. I am not in a position to carry out simulations myself.

Available applets demonstrate the 2/3 probability but they may be programmed to make Monty choose either door with probability 1/2.

Comment: this is such a popular problem. It has been analyzed numerous times.... please search on net.

Comment: You don't need to do a simulation. Just write out a list of every possible thing that can happen - there's not that many of them (if you don't want to do any thinking at all to reduce the state space, it's 3 for where the car is, times 3 for which door I pick first, times 2 for whether I switch, conditionally times 2 for which door I switch to). But anyway, we can't know whether your reasoning was valid, because you didn't give any.

Comment: The analyses I have seen assume that when Monty has a choice of doors to open, he gives a 50-50 chance to each door. I am asking what happens if it is not 50-50. I have not found anything about this possibility on the net. If it is found on the net, I would appreciate a reference or a link. I am also asking about simulations when it is not 50-50.

Comment: At least this is a variant I never heard before. But I agree Patrick's comment.

Comment: Wikipedia gives the analysis of several variants. Did you have a look at them ?

Comment: You can calculate the probabilities with Bayes's rule also if the probability which door is opened are different. But this makes only sense , if it is specified how this is done (for example , the smaller number with probability $0.25$)

Comment: The most diabolic variant is that Monty Hall opens a door ONLY if we choose the car-door. Now switching loses always , and not switching wins , but only if a door was opened because we chose the car-door , so that we only have a 1:3 chance.

Comment: Yes, the probability to switch doesn't change. The whole point to the problem is that the contestant will be right one third of the time and wrong two thirds of the time. Switching turns wrong guesses into correct guesses so the probability to win is $\frac{2}{3}$, regardless of a single outcome.

Comment: @JohnDouma Do you mean that the probability of winning does not depend on the probability with which some wrong door is opened ?

Comment: @Peter No. I mean the probability of getting the right answer doesn't change because someone guessed correctly on one play of the game. If you simulate the game, you will guess correctly one third of the time. The point is that Monty knows where the prize is so by switching you always get the right door when you were originally wrong.

Comment: @JohnDouma But this is not true, if Monty Hall opens the door ONLY if we originally guess right. If we are wrong, we do not have this option. And without knowing the rules , we cannot know what Monty Hall does.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand what you are saying. In the Monty Hall problem, regardless of what door you pick, Monty opens another that doesn't contain the prize. He then asks if you want to switch. I don't understand your point about Monty's decision to open a door.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139380/discussion-between-peter-and-john-douma).

Comment: @JohnDouma  Peter is referring to a  variant of the Monty Hall version that is not like the standard Monty Hall problem. In this variant, Monty will open another door if you initially picked the door with the prize, but he does not open any door if you did not initially pick the door with the prize. The Wikipedia page calls this the 'Monty from Hell' variant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem#Other_host_behaviors   The OP's version is the second of the variants listed there ... where if you set $p=1$ you get what is known as the 'Lazy Monty' or 'Monty Crawl' variant.

Comment: @Bram28 But is that what is being asked here? I didn't see any mention of Monty not opening the door.

Comment: @JohnDouma Right. The OP is asking about the 'Lazy Monty' variant, not the 'Monty from Hell' variant.

Comment: @JohnDouma My beef with most presentations of this puzzle, including the first presentation on the Wikipedia page and the presentation in the vos Savant column, is that they just tell a story of some events (this happened, then that happened) without any mention of the **rules** of the game. Without making some assumption about the rules, we don't know if we have standard Monty, or Lazy Monty, or Monty from Hell. And the worst part of that is that Monty from Hell gives an exact opposite answer to standard Monty. (But this question makes the rules explicit, so it's fine.)

Answer (score 4):

Your Monty Hall variant is known as the '[Monty Crawl](http://probability.ca/jeff/writing/montyfall.pdf)' or '[Lazy Monty](https://medium.com/intellectually-yours/the-monty-hall-problem-609bd0d7020)' (the door with the lower number is closer to Monty) scenario. With that additional assumption it depends on what door was opened. For example, let's take the problem description from the [Wikipedia page on the Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem#Other_host_behaviors):

> Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors, opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you, "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch your choice?

In this case, it should be clear that door 2 contains the prize if Monty is indeed lazy (if door 2 would have had a goat, Lazy Monty would have opened up door 2). So in this scenario you should definitely switch, as you have a 100% chance of getting the car by picking door 2.

OK, but what if we had:

> Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors, opens another door, say No. 2, which has a goat. He then says to you, "Do you want to pick door No. 3?" Is it to your advantage to switch your choice?

Well, now it doesn't matter whether you switch or not. It turns out to be 50-50

To see the math for the latter (simulations are fine, but math is better :P )

Let $Pi$ be the event of you picking door $i$, $Gi$ the event of Monty revealing a goat behind door $i$, and $Ci$ the event of the car being behind doors $i$

So what we want to know is:  Given $P1$ and $G2$, what is the chance of the car being behind door $1$ ... and what is the chance of it being behind door $3$? That is, what are $P(C1|G2,P1)$ and $P(C3|G2,P1)$?

Well, let's first point out that:

$$P(G2|C3, P1) = 1$$ (Monty is forced to open door $2$ if you pick door $1$ and the car is behind door $3$)

$$P(G2|C1,P1)=1$$ (Monty could open door $2$ or $3$, but since Monty is lazy, Monty will definitely open up door $2$ ... this is of course where this Lazy Monty variant differs from the original Monty Hall problems, where we set $P(G2|C1,P1)=P(G3|C1,P1)=\frac{1}{2}$. With Lazy Monty, we have $P(G3|C1,P1) = 0$ )

Of course we also have $$P(G2|C2 , P1) = 0$$ (it is impossible for Monty to reveal a goat behind door $2$ if it has a car)

OK, so: $$P(G2|P1) = P(G2|P1,C1)*P(C1) + P(G2|P1,C2)*P(C2) + P(G2|P1,C3)*P(C3)$$

$$= 1 * \frac{1}{3} + 0 * \frac{1}{3} + 1 * \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

So: $$P(C3 | G2 , P1) = \frac{P(G2|C3 , P1) * P(C3|P1)}{P(G2|P1)} = \frac{1 * \frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Sanity check: $$P(C1 | G2 , P1) = \frac{P(G2|C1 , P1) * P(C1|P1)}{P(G2|P1)} = \frac{1 * \frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So yeah, in that scenario it does not matter whether you switch or not.

You can use these same formulas to explore what happens when Monty prefers a certain door with a certain likelihood (e.g. $P(G2|C1,P1)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $P(G3|C1,P1)=\frac{1}{4}$), but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: What is meant with "lazy" ? Must Monty Hall open the door ? Usually some assitant does this or it is even done automatically.

Comment: @Peter It's explained in the link I put in my post .. but yes, it is assumed that Monty opens the door. This is nothing specific to the Lazy Monty version: most presentations of the Monty Hall problem have Monty open a door .. see fort example the Wikipedia presentation in my post. But yes, being lazy, Monty opens the closest one that has a goat.

Comment: I was not confused about the variant and the reason why Monty Hall does this. I just wondered whether in a real show he would actually open the door himself.

Comment: @Peter Since the real show never had a game anything like this, who knows? But I've always assumed he "opens" a door in the sense that Mr. Blandings "built" his dream house.

Comment: @Bram28 You have answered the question, "if the contestant *always* opens door 1 and Monty *always* opens door 2 (car is never behind door 2) and the contestant *always* switches, what proportion of the time will the contestant win?" This is different from the question, "If the car is randomly placed, the contestant initially chooses a door randomly, Monty opens a goat door and the contestant then *always* switches, what proportion of the time will the contestant win?" The answer to the latter question is $\tfrac {2}{3}$, regardless of how Monty chooses a goat door to open.

Comment: @Satish Yes, that is correct. So as you can see: the problem description really matters for the Monty Hall problem: it matters as far as what you can assume about Monty ( does Monty always open a door with a goat? Does Monty even  know where the car is? And if Monty has a choice, does he have a preference?) But also: are we given what door you pick and what door Monty opens?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a computer to simulate this if the simulation is for you and not for a course.

You'll need a six sided die. For the die, let a roll of $1$ or $2$ be a $1$, let a $3$ or $4$ be a $2$ and let a $5$ or a $6$ be a $3$. You'll use these outcomes to select the door that holds the prize.

Write down your guess and then roll the die. It's more fun if you have a friend guess. Then write down whether you win or lose with each of the two strategies.

You'll find that the switching strategy still gives you a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of winning as in the online applets.

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer: chance for the contestant to win the prize, under
> optimal policy, is $2/3$ in this variant, the same as in the
> usual version of the game under the change doors optimal policy.

There are 3 possible positions for the prize vs goat (consider the doors are in order 1 to 3, left to right):
$$P-G-G\ \ \ \ \ \ \ G-P-G \ \ \ \ \ \  G-G-P$$
Suppose door 1 was chosen by the contestant (marked with a $c$, e.g. $\overset{c}{P}$), and Monty chooses the first possible door left to right (marked with an $m$, e.g. $\overset{m}{G}$):
$$\overset{c}{P}-\overset{m}{G}-G\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \overset{c}{G}-P-\overset{m}{G} \ \ \ \ \ \  \overset{c}{G}-\overset{m}{G}-P$$

1. If contestant picks door 1 and Monty picks door 3: best option is changing doors. $\text{Pr(Win)=1}$
2. If contestant picks door 1 and Monty picks door 2: keeping the door or changing door will both lead to $\text{Pr(Win)=1/2}$

Therefore, given that the 3 configurations Prize-Goat have probability $1/3$, the overall probability of winning for a contestant choosing door 1 and following an optimal policy is: $$\text{Pr(Win|Door 1 chosen and optimal policy)}=\dfrac{1}{3}\times 1 + \dfrac{2}{3}\times \dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{2}{3}$$
Same result will be obtained if door 2 or door 3 had been originally choosen by the contestant.

Notice that $2/3$ is also the probability of winning under the change door policy in the original version of this game.

Comment: To Bluemaster: According to @Bram28 above, the probability of the contestant winning the prize with the optimal policy (always switch) is (1/2) in this variant and not (2/3). So, which is it — (1/2) or  (2/3) ?? I think a computer simulation will provide some indication.

Comment: @Satish I believe you misread what Brams28 said... he also found 2/3 as the overall probability of switching (as the overal probability). What happens is that the probability is 1 (in the case Monty chooses door 3, when contestant chooses door 1), and 1/2 in the other cases. There is no need of any computer simulation. This is a theoretical result. The simulation will naturally agree with that but is not needed in this case.